# BackgroundWorker stopping when a handled exception happens

Tags: c#, email, smtp, backgroundworker

In a WinForms application I run several BackgroundWorkers to send bulk email. (No, it's not spam, it's corporate email).

From time to time, a **SmtpException ('Failure sending mail')** happens when sending the email. This SmtpException is thrown inside a try-catch and written in a log. However, when this exception in particular happens, it takes about 5 minutes to write the exception to the log and continue, after which every email fails with the same exception (and it takes about 5 minutes for it to handle each failed email).

From my research I've read that a BackgroundWorker stops when an unhandled exception is thrown in debug mode. However, I've ran the project with debug and release configurations, and the behavior is the same. **Even when in debug mode, the BackgroundWorker stops for a long time without the debugger popping up any exception message.**

Also note that this bug is difficult to reproduce, as the first SmtpException with message 'Failure sending mail' is thrown when it has sent between 300-800 emails, at seemingly random points.

For logging I'm just using Trace from System.Diagnostics, so I don't think that's the problem.

EDIT: I should also add that in some rare occasions, when SmtpException with message 'Failure sending mail', the BackgroundWorker stops going through the emails completely. I let it hang there just for the hell of it and after 1 hour or so it continued sending emails like nothing happened.

Here's the code of DoWork:

```
private void sender_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    SalaryEmail[] emails = e.Argument as SalaryEmail[];

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SalaryEmail.SmtpCredentials.User, SalaryEmail.SmtpCredentials.Password);

    foreach (SalaryEmail email in emails)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Sending and database operations here
            email.Send(ref smtpClient);

            // In this case I only report progress to a progressBar with previously set steps, so the number is irrelevant
            worker.ReportProgress(0);
        }
    }

    smtpClient.Dispose();
}
```

Here's SalaryEmail.Send:

```
public bool Send(ref SmtpClient smtpClient)
{
    bool sent = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            // Mail is a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage non-static property created and configured previously within the class
            smtpClient.Send(Mail); 
            sent = true;
        }
        catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Intento " + i + " SmtpException: " + smtpEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Intento " + i + " Error al enviar: " + ex.Message);
        }

        // Update database
        if (sent)
        {
            try
            {
                Database.MarkAsSent(Qna, RFC);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Error al marcar enviados" + e.Message);
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return sent;
}
```

Exception detail:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
02/01/2014 12:57:25 Intento 0 SmtpException: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Error al enviar correo. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación.
   en System.Net.ConnectionPool.Get(Object owningObject, Int32 result, Boolean& continueLoop, WaitHandle[]& waitHandles)
   en System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   en MailingClient.SalaryEmail.Send(SmtpClient& smtpClient) en C:\Users\mrivera\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PayrollMailing\MailingClient\SalaryEmail.cs:línea 62
```

Trace:

```
02/01/2014 1:44:56 Sending email...
02/01/2014 1:45:01 Updating database...
02/01/2014 1:45:01 Sending email...
02/01/2014 1:45:06 Updating database...
02/01/2014 1:45:07 Sending email...
02/01/2014 1:45:11 Updating database...
02/01/2014 1:45:11 Sending email...
<exception posted above here>
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1890) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x444) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xb90) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b00) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2754) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x978) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x18b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x24fc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x18c0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xa1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Take a look at the InnerException to see if that gives you a better clue.  My guess is that the server can't keep up with the flood of incoming requests, and 5 minutes sounds like a timeout to me.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Smtp timeout exceptions happen too but they are handled correctly. There's also an exception with the message 'Submission rate has been exceeded', which is also handled correctly. I will reproduce it again and take a look at the InnerException, will post back here with results.

Comment: @WonkotheSane My Visual Studio is in spanish so I'll do my best translating the inner exception message: "Unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection has been interrupted by the remote host"

Comment: _'Submission rate has been exceeded'_ and then the Server applies throttling with 5 min timeouts. Mystery solved.

Comment: A VERY similar problem is discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29cabe89-db35-48ae-bc54-91b583eeed55/smtpexception-during-heavy-email-processing), however the conclussion they reached was that it is a host problem. I highly doubt it is a host problem because my host is smtp.office365.com

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm aware of the submission rate limit of Office 365 (I'll save you a google search: 30 emails per minute). This type of exception is handled correctly: the Office 365 SMTP server rejects emails until the submission rate is reduced.

Comment: You say "handled correctly" but without the code we can't verify that. Set timeouts on your communications and make sure you handle and extensively log all exceptions. The problem is not in the Bgw or in the Smtp client.

Comment: By "handled correctly" I mean that my application handles it correctly, it tries sending the email again and succeeds if the submission rate is under the limit.

Comment: The posted code is irrelevant, show (the main parts of) email.Send()

Comment: @HenkHolterman added SalaryEmail.Send code, let me know if you want me to add more code.

Comment: OK: 1) lose the `ref` modifier, it has no function. 2) log the _entire_ exception, not just the message. `Write(e.ToStrign());` 3) set `smtpClient.TimeOut = 2000;` 4) add a trace just _before_ sending an email (and maybe before updating the db). 5) Log the remaining exceptions in the Bgw Completed event (e.Error).

Comment: The default timeout is 100 seconds, what is MAX_ATTEMPTS?

Comment: 1) I actually need to pass a reference, because I don't want to create and dispose a SmtpClient object for every email, as that would require authentication for every email.
2) & 4) Done, will post back with results
3) You've said it yourself
5) I don't see how this is relevant, if there were any other exceptions that I didn't handle the debugger would break

Comment: MAX_ATTEMPS is just an int with value 3

Comment: @HenkHolterman I found nothing interesting printing the whole exception. It prints a similar message: "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation timed out.", then prints the call stack up to SmtpClient.Send

Comment: And is there an InnerException?

Comment: No, there is no InnerException :/ I've only identified 2 kinds of exceptions that cause this problem:
1) 'Failure sending email' which has an InnerException of "Unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection has been interrupted by the remote host"
2) 'The operation timed out'

Comment: Something interesting is that when the program stops sending email, messages of the type 'The thread '<No Name>' (0x1890) has exited with code 0 (0x0).' are written to the trace from time to time. These messages are written when the program is sending email successfully, so I don't know if it has something to do with the problem

Comment: Regarding 1) You don't need `ref`. It's harmless here but confusing. 5) The root problems are usually where "I don't see how this is relevant".

Comment: MAX_ATTEMPS * default_timeout = 3 * 100sec = 5 minutes, so it is kind of clear what is happening. You need to work with the (limitations of the) Server, not force-feed it with a for-loop.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll take a different approach and see how it goes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Finally solved it with SendAsync and implementing logic in the application to not upload more than 30 mails per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BackgroundWorker stops with exception and that exception can be found in Completed event of worker. you can check the stacktrace of it. in order to stop process preemption due to exception you should have DoWork in try catch

> If the operation raises an exception that your code does not handle,
>   the BackgroundWorker catches the exception and passes it into the
>   RunWorkerCompleted event handler, where it is exposed as the Error
>   property of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs. If you
>   are running under the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger will break
>   at the point in the DoWork event handler where the unhandled exception
>   was raised.

register to RunWorkerCompleted event to get detailed trace of exception

```
public void MyProg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Error != null) {
        // You have an exception, which you can examine through the e.Error property.
        //display your exception details here
    } else {
        // No exception in DoWork.
       //happy ending
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding sending bulk emails i would suggest to use SendAsync instead of Send method from SmtpClient. Also for some reason your smtp might be rejecting to receive email messages from your app so try to encapsulate your each email sending logic and try to debug that particular email you found exception and try to lower mail/seconds using some threshold(30 mails per seconds) to avoid hyperactivity at SMTP server.

Comment: All exceptions thrown in the BackgroundWorker are inside a try-catch, so they're handled by user code. There are no unhandled exceptions as far as I know, because the debugger does not break when I run it in debug mode.

Comment: do you have DoWork method a main try catch?

Comment: No, I don't have the whole thing inside a try-catch. Just the email-construction, sending and database operations are inside try-catch. What I understand from reading the documentation is that if there is any exception **not handled by my code** the debugger will break when I run it (in debug mode obviously). However, in this case the debugger does not break.

Comment: I've added the DoWork code, let me know if you want me to add more code.

Comment: you code looks ok, if you want to send multiple emails i would suggest to use SendAsync instead of Send method from SmtpClient. also for some reason your smtp might be rejecting to receive email messages from your app so try to encapsulate your each email sending logic and try to debug that particular email you found exception.

Comment: Finally solved it with SendAsync and implementing logic in the application to not upload more than 30 mails per minute. You should put that in the answer so if anyone has a similar problem they see it.